# How to make a NavigationView background transparent in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview

I have a NavigationView being shown upon another View, and I need to make it transparent or change it's background color opacity to see the View beneath it. How can I achieve this? (iOS 14.0+)

Comment: One way might be to use the new Materials introduced in WWDC 21 for iOS 15

Comment: @loremipsum can you point to one, pls?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Material

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71040160/how-to-make-navigationview-background-transparent-swiftui seems to be answered here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Make NavigationView Background Transparent SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71040160/how-to-make-navigationview-background-transparent-swiftui)