# SwiftUI TabView not working due to NavigationLink hierarchy

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, ios-navigationview

I have a TabView with three Views which are my main views when the app is launched. In some Views, I have NavigationLinks to open DetailViews. When these are dismissed, the user is returned to the View in the TabView that the user was on originally before opening a NavigationLink. However, from then on setting the selection variable for the TabView programmatically does not work. I have three custom buttons to navigate through the TabView Views as an alternative to swiping left and right.

When the buttons are pressed, the TabView index indicator changes, so I suppose the TabView has registered the change in the binding variable, however, the View does not change. Swiping left and right does work.

On my NavigationView I use a custom back button which seems to be the issue. When using `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`, the issue occurs. Otherwise it works fine.

How can I solve this while using my custom back button?

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
    
            NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $viewRouter.currentView) {
                Text("Leaderboard")
                    .tag(Views.leaderboard)
                
                Text("Home")
                    .tag(Views.home)
                
                PouleView()
                    .tag(Views.poules)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())              
            
            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
                    Text("Leaderboard")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewRouter.changeView(destination: Views.leaderboard)
                        }
                    
                    Text("Home")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewRouter.changeView(destination: Views.home)
                        }
                    
                    Text("Poule")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewRouter.changeView(destination: Views.poules)
                        }
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct PouleView: View {
    
    @State var navigateToDetailView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: PouleDetailView() , isActive: $navigateToDetailView) { EmptyView() }

            Button(action: {
                self.navigateToDetailView = true
            }) {
               Text("Open Detail")
            }
            
        }
    }
}


struct PouleDetailView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
               Text("Close")
            }
            Text("This is content")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("",displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)

    }
}
```

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var onboarding: Bool = false
    @Published var currentView: Views = .home
    @Published var originView: Views = .home
    
    func changeView(destination: Views) {
        withAnimation() {
            self.originView = self.currentView
            self.currentView = destination
        }
    }
}

enum Views: Equatable, Hashable {
    case home
    case poules
    case leaderboard
}
```

Comment: `In some Views, I have NavigationStacks which open DetailViews.`, where do you have your NavigationStacks? I don't see any in your bits of code.  Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine sorry that was a mistake, I updated the text accordingly. The code provided is minimal reproducible and contains the issue once run in Xcode.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless, to use NavigationLinks you need to have a NavigationStack, where is it? As an aside, I don't think you should use `withAnimation` inside a `class`, it is for recomputing the view’s body with the provided animation.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip on the animations. NavigationStacks are only supported from iOS 16 and on, while my codebase should support iOS 14+. Using NavigationLinks are the more traditional ways of navigating, iOS 16+ provides more neat ways of navigating, but I am unable to use the Stack.

Comment: use the deprecated `NavigationView` then, but you must have one wrapping the views, otherwise the`NavigationLinks` will not work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970939/swiftui-hide-tabview-bar-inside-navigationlink-views

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162743/interacting-with-a-confirmationdialog-or-alert-is-causing-the-parent-view-to-pop/74163592#74163592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: put your NavigationStacks (or NavigationViews) -inside- the single tabs, not outside of them.

Long answer: Navigation patterns are a complicated topic. There is a lot of content out there, and I would suggest starting with the Apple WWDC talks about this. Your current root view is the tab view, instead of a specific tab that is returned to, so that is what is being “returned” to by the navigation.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that and that fixed the issue indeed. However, there are backgrounds properties that need to be displayed behind all TabViews. When placing the TabViews within a NavigationView, the background is not visible anymore and there have been many other discussions about it (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73334234/14855422). I have solved it by using a VStack on the Tabs with the NavigationView with the NavigationLink inside it set with opacity 0, which is very hacky but does the trick. I have seen WWDC talks, but these NavigationViews are from older iOS versions which I need.